# why lambda expression doesn't write `.class` but inner class do

Tags: java, java-8

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
        }
    };

    Comparator<String> comparator1 = (String a, String b) -> {
        return Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length());
    };


    Comparator<String> comparator2 = Comparator.comparing(String::length);

}
```

class file:
LambdaAndAnonymousInner$1.class and
LambdaAndAnonymousInner.class

the LambdaAndAnonymousInner$1.class is `comparator`

`comparator1` and `comparator2` doesn't write `.class` file

I wonder why it happened

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because lambdas are invoked dynamically.

Refer to this: http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/1/1e/2011_Goetz_Lambda.pdf